# Which Continuous Integration tooling is best for for Windows Azure backend + native apps on multiple platforms?

Tags: cross-platform, continuous-integration

We will soon start Developing a solution where the backend is Windows Azure Cloud running sql database and C# Rest Web services, and an ASP.Net public Website. 
Plus native apps for multiple Mobile platforms to consume the webservices: Android, iOS, and maybe Windows Phone later. 
Possibly could be Windows and Mac desktop versions of the apps needed at some point later

I have not set up continuous integration before and would like recommendation as to which CI tool is best for this kind of multiple platform development.

We have been using TFS for Source Code Control of the prototypes. Not sure though of TFS suitability for CI purposes vs other tools such as say Jenkins when there are many OS platforms to build for.

Can anyone suggest what is the most appropriate Continuous Integration tool in this instance?